# Safari - How do I create pixel-perfect layouts without PixelPlugin (firefox addon)?

Tags: firefox-addon, safari-extension

PixelPerfect is an FF addon that overlays an image onto the browser viewport. Is there an alternative or port of this addon/extension for safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only be useful if it's you own site, but maybe: http://codecanyon.net/item/xprecise/78685